# FabricJS custom filter in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

I have binary/grayscale image and I want to filter that image that all white color became transparent and all dark color change to some user specific color.

I have a problem to create custom filter in angular. All example I found are for pure JavaScript and demo page does not work http://fabricjs.com/image-filters.

What I tried, from information I have:

```
private canvas: fabric.Canvas;

constructor() { this.initializeNewFilter()  }

initializeNewFilter() {
  fabric.Image.filters['Redify'] = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter, {

  type: 'Redify',

  applyTo: function (canvasEl) {
    const context = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height);
    const data = imageData.data;

    for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      data[i + 1] = 0;
      data[i + 2] = 0;
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }
});

fabric.Image.filters['Redify'].fromObject = function (object) {
  return new fabric.Image.filters['Redify'](object);
};
```

}

Even in this base example I get error:

```
 ERROR TypeError: canvasEl.getContext is not a function
```

`const context = canvasEl.getContext('2d')`  // getContext('2d') does not exists, but canvasEl is here

Also I do not know how to send via custom filter, is there any better explanation ?

Comment: I am having the same problem - it looks to me via Chrome devtools that the webGL  context is being sent which doesn't have the necesssary fns - it does't seem they've added any filter migration guide or anything to the docs, and I cannot find any help in the github issues either. Seems this should be so easy but it's not with current examples...

Comment: @Stacey Reiman I solved this problem outside of FabricJS library. I loaded image in my own canvas, manipulated with the pixels (execute my custom filter) and then send already prepared image to FabricJS.  I checked the code of FabricJS and they do the similar process with custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the filtering engine you are using, getContext is available for fabric.Canvas2dFilterBackend().

try

```
fabric.initFilterBackend = function() {      
    return (new fabric.Canvas2dFilterBackend());    
};
```

reference:
[FabricJS filtering overview](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-filters)